# Different handling table td-height in IE vs. all others?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html-table

I have a problem with TABLES in all internet explorer versions, or rather with the height of TDs that drive me nuts.

I have the following markup

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr style="vertical-align:top;">
            <td id="TD1" width="35" colspan="2" style="background-color:yellow; height:1%;">
                <div id="DIV1" style="height:10px; background-color:red;"></div>
            </td>
            <td id="TD2" width="15" rowspan="2" style="height:99%;">
                <div id="DIV2" style="height:160px; background-color:green;"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="vertical-align:top;">
            <td id="TD3" width="25">
                <div id="DIV3" style="height:60px; background-color:blue;"></div>
            </td>
            <td id="TD4" width="10">
                <div id="DIV4" style="height:80px; background-color:orange;"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

For a better understanding you can execute the code in the tryit-editor from w3schools.com

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_td_height.

I think that explains, what I try to explain :)

While the height of DIV2 is smaller or equal than the height of DIV1 and DIV3 or DIV4 it works like expected. But when the height of DIV2 is bigger than the height of DIV1 and DIV3 or DIV4, the IE rises TD1 in the same ratio like TD3 and TD4.

In all other browsers, only TD3 and TD4 raises. TD1 has still the same height like DIV1.

Has someone an idea or a workaround how I can fix this?

A tableless layout is sadly no option.

Comment: First thing to check is that IE isn't in Quirks Mode. Also, what version(s) of IE are you testing with?

Comment: Without a proper doctype, you will never get IE to attempt to perform like the other far more modern browsers. IE is in quirks mode.

Comment: @Spudley IE7 (compatibility mode), IE8, IE9

Answer (score 0):

Without a proper doctype, you will never get IE to attempt to perform like the other far more modern browsers. IE is in quirks mode. Use this one:
`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">`

or this one:

`<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: I think the doctype is proper:

 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="de" lang="de">
 
document.compatMode is CSS1compat

Comment: @elweilando - New web pages have no use for the transitional doctype. Transitional is for 'transitioning' from old, deprecated markup. Always use strict doctypes.

Comment: I tried both declarations, but it changes nothing. Html5 as well as xhtml strict make in this case the same as transitional.

Comment: @elweilando - there are other things which can trigger quirks mode, but without seeing your actual page we can't tell much more about what's happening.

Comment: @elweilando - The second doctype is a standards mode doctype and should not be confused with anything HTML5.